# Does the concatenation of NULL + 'something' always yield NULL? Why?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to apply an OUTER APPLY computation on every row of a set. This computation concatenates a number of string fields into one but sometimes theses fields are null or filled with empty strings. The concatenation uses '-' as a delimiter between fields, so when they are empty ('') the result is '----' instead of a NULL, the result I'd like to get.

Before doing this computation I need to check the value of these fields.

How would you do it?

I thought about using NULLIF and it seems that it behaves as I expect, but I don't know why.

Will the concatenation of NULL +'something' always be NULL? Why?

```
SELECT 
string_1,
string_2,
string_3,
string_4,
string_5,
string_concat,
FROM Table1
OUTER APPLY(VALUES(NULLIF(string_1,'')+'-'+NULLIF(string_2,'')+'-'+NULLIF(string_3,'')+'-'+NULLIF(string_4,'')+'-'+NULLIF(string_5,''))) v1(string_concat)
```

Table1 doesn't have any index and I can't implement any.

Is this code better in terms of performance than doing a CASE in the SELECT?

I like it because the code looks more clean, though.

Comment: Add the database tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does the concatenation of NULL + NULL + 'something' always be NULL?
>   Why?

This depends on [`SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-concat-null-yields-null-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) setting. If it is `ON` (the default) then yes concatenating a `NULL` with the `+` operator will always yield `NULL`

I'd probably do it like this though

```
SELECT string_1,
       string_2,
       string_3,
       string_4,
       string_5,
       string_concat,
FROM   Table1
       CROSS APPLY(VALUES (NULLIF(CONCAT(string_1, '-', string_2, '-', string_3, '-', string_4, '-', string_5), '----')) ) v1(string_concat)
```

so only one `NULLIF` is needed - on the `CONCAT` result.

As the `VALUES` clause always returns exactly one row you can use `CROSS APPLY`

Comment: Thanks for  the 'NULL answer' and for your solution. Do you think that doing this in the FROM clause is faster/better than doing it in the SELECT with a CASE, or there is no significant difference?

Comment: No - it shouldn't be any different. So just a matter of preference if you prefer to move the longer calculation out of the `SELECT` for readability

Comment: Thanks again. I like it for readability but also because I could use the calculated field in any other part of the query if I needed: further calculations on the concatenated string, on the WHERE clause, ...

Comment: Yep, if you need to reference the alias elsewhere then the `APPLY` is a handy trick

Answer (score 1):

> Will the concatenation of NULL +'something' always be NULL? Why?

Aside the technical explanation that has already been given, you may be interested in the logical motivation on why it is like that.

NULL actually means you don't know something or that something is not applicable and therefore not usable in that context. So anything you do with something you don't know, or doesn't make sense, will yield an "I still don't know/doesn't make sense" result.

For example: let's say a friend of yours has 2 cars, and another friends of yours has some cars but you don't know how many. If I would ask you how many cars your friends have in total, that only answer you could give me is that you don't really know.

Hope this helps to understand. The issue with NULL is much bigger than this as it involves 3-valued-logic instead of the more common and well understood 2-valued-logic. Here's more detail on the issue: http://www.dbdebunk.com/2017/04/null-value-is-contradiction-in-terms.html